why is python's zip strictness only enforced when the object is used, not created
In the following example, why is the ValueError only raised on the last line rather than when Z is created?
l1 = [3]
l2 = [1,2]

Z = zip(l1, l2, strict=True)
Zlist = list(Z)


zip() works on arbitrary iterables, which don't necessarily have any ability to determine their length in advance.  Yes, it could have detected the problem earlier in this particular case, but that wouldn't eliminate the need for the end-of-iteration check, and would result in inconsistent behavior depending on the exact type of the arguments.

From the documentation "zip() is lazy: The elements won’t be processed until the iterable is iterated on, e.g. by a for loop or by wrapping in a list."

Z is a generator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python
